# Ошибка перелистывание в galaxy s4 viewpager fragment с imageview android

Tags: android-viewpager, android, listview, android-fragment

Сейчас такая проблема:
приложение работает в других устройствах.

Проверил в:
Galaxy grand prime  
Galaxy A5
Galaxy s3 mini
Galaxy s4 mini
Galaxy Tab S
Alcatel One Touch

Все работает. Но когда установил программу на galaxy s4 c андроидом 4.2.2 и 4.4.2, выводит, что приложение остановлено.
У меня есть ListView, в котором при нажатии на них перенаправляет на позицию в viewpager.
В других устройствах перенаправление работает, а в galaxy s4 не работает.

Вот код, который отвечает на перенаправления:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, null);
    int pNumber;
    pNumber=pageNumber+1;
    ImageView tvPage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPage);
//когда id создается динамично не работает
//когда id статично getIdentifier("a1", "drawable", getPackageName()); все отлично работает
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("a"+Integer.toString(pNumber), "drawable", getPackageName());
    tvPage.setImageResource(id);
    return view;
}
```

Ребята, что я делаю не так?

Comment: стактрейс где? По кофейной гуще не гадаем тут...

Comment: И нема кода pager-a и ClickListener-a.